# C++ circular dependency - namespace vs struct

Tags: c++, namespaces

Please educate me.  Why does this compile:

```
struct compiles
{
    struct A;
    struct B
    {
        B(const A &a) : member(a.member) { }
        int member;
    };
    struct A
    {
        A(const B &b) : member(b.member) { }
        int member;
    };
};
```

while this does not:

```
namespace doesnt
{
    struct A;
    struct B
    {
        B(const A &a) : member(a.member) { }
        int member;
    };
    struct A
    {
        A(const B &b) : member(b.member) { }
        int member;
    };
}
```

(in MSVC 9.0)

Comment: What's the compiler error you're getting?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In C++, class scope is special. Any declaration that extends to or past then end of the class definition is automatically extended to the regions defined by its member definitions (3.3.6 [basic.scope.class]).

This means that in the first case both the first declaration of `struct A` and the full definition of `struct A` are visible in the body of `B` and its constructor.

This doesn't apply to namespace scope so in the second case `a.member` in the constructor of `B` is an error because a definition of `struct A` isn't yet visible.

Answer (score 14):

The body of a `class`/`struct`/`union` definition is processed all at once, allowing references to members of classes defined later.  A `namespace` is processed from top to bottom, and a forward declaration of `struct A` does not allow you to use its members without a definition.  Try moving the definition of `B`'s constructor out-of-class so you can put it after the definition of `A`.

Answer (score 3):

[Also tested with g++ 4.2] The first one compiles because the compiler fully picks up all the types defined within the struct before actually compiling the nested structures (think about public inline methods using private attributes that appear later within the class). Within the namespace the compiler simply works top-to-bottom and doesn't have special rules.

Answer (score 0):

both will compile if you move the implementations of the constructors to the .cpp file where they should be anyway.