# C++ Why is circular dependency possible within a class but not a namespace or global scope?

Tags: c++, circular-dependency

I came across the following code in [an article](http://strlen.com/java-style-classes-in-c)

```
struct entire_program   
{
    struct B;

    struct A
    {
        B *bbb;
        void Aa() { B bb; bb.Bb(); };
    };

    struct B
    {
        A aaa;
        void Bb() { A aa; aa.Aa(); };
    };
};
```

Why am I allowed to call method `Bb()` in this case, but if I change `struct entire_program` to `namespace entire_program` it generates a compiler error?

I already read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4938935/c-circular-dependency-namespace-vs-struct), what I am asking is: if it is possible to call methods that are undefined yet within classes/structs/unions **why don't namespaces work the same way?** I am interested in the motivation behind this behavior.

[Related question on Programmers.SE](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/180237/java-style-classes-in-c) (for those interested in the coding style presented in the article)

Comment: They don't work this way because they were never intended to work this way - namespaces allow random declarations in random locations, while class/struct/union declarations must be within the same file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is just the way classes and namespaces work in C++. Classes *have* to bring the entire set of (class member) names as candidates because otherwise you'd have a huge burden of ordering your class members and might not conveniently be able to order your public interface first, for example.

Namespaces on the other hand work almost exactly like C functions and are processed sequentially in the order they're listed in the source file. Special features aren't needed since you can always declare your function before calling it at namespace/global scope.

Answer (score 1):

Circular dependency is possible inside both classes and namespaces. It is just a matter of defining things correctly in circular dependency situations.

In your case the code compiled with `struct entire_program` because of special treatment in-class member function definitions: they are allowed to "see" the entire definition of the enclosing class(es), both above and below the current point. But they cannot see the entire definition of the enclosing namespace. With namespaces the compiler only sees what has been declared above the current point.

Classes and namespaces are very different things, so the problem of switching freely between the two does not usually arise in practice. But just for illustrative purposes this can be achieved in many cases, including your artificial example

```
namespace entire_program   
{
    struct B;

    struct A
    {
        B *bbb;
        void Aa();
    };

    struct B
    {
        A aaa;
        void Bb() { A aa; aa.Aa(); }
    };
}

inline void entire_program::A::Aa()
{
  B bb; bb.Bb();
}
```

My implementation above has the same effect as yours, but it does not rely on that special treatment of member functions. You can freely switch between `struct entire_program` and `namespace entire_program`, if you so desire. Just remember that namespace definition does not have a `;` after the closing `}`.